# In musescore, is there a way to automatically create a guitar or bass tab from existing notation and keep them in sync?

Tags: tablature, musescore

I use [MuseScore](https://musescore.org/) on [Ubuntu 15](http://www.ubuntu.com/). In a couple of pieces I have an existing music as such

[image]

**In musescore, is there a way to automatically create a guitar or bass tab from these lines?** Moreover is it possible to keep these the bass line and bass tab in sync? This is if I change one, will the other correspond?

**Edit/Update**: From the comments (upvoted), I just realized I was running an older copy. I've just [updated to version 2.x](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-musescore-2-0-0-on-ubuntu-15-04-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-and-derivative-systems/).

Comment: Are you sure you are on Musescore 2.x? The tab feature is not in version 1.x.

Comment: Well now that you mention it, I got 1.3. I installed via `apt-get`. Perhaps the Ubuntu repos are behind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you pointed out, there are different ways to work with tabs in Musescore, which are listed [here](https://musescore.org/en/node/7845).

The one you are trying to implement is this one:

[image: Instructions]

It seems that you are using an older version of Musescore (1.x), in which the tab feature is not available. I'm on 2.0.1 and can see the `advanced style properties` menu:

[image: Screen]